# Trouble with Wildcard Subdomain and private nameservers on Plesk 10

Tags: subdomain, wildcard

So Im currently with Media Temple on a DV server and we're running Plesk 10.

We've been trying to set the domain up by this article Media Temple have :

[http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv):Configure_a_wildcard_subdomain](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29:Configure_a_wildcard_subdomain)

instead of routing to the domain, eg test.domain.com -> domain.com, it just brought us to a media temple server default page.

After trying to set up the wildcard subdomains in a few ways, media temple told us that it wasnt working because of private nameservers, and it was out of the scope of their support.

We're pretty puzzled on how to get this working. Has anyone had any experience with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an outdated recipe in the article. If your server is up to date and you have Plesk 10.4, adding a wildcard subdomain should be much easier: just "Add subdomain" and type "*" in its name (there would be comments on the screen suggesting it).